# Blackberry - Setting an alarm programmatically?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Is there an API for the Blackberry on changing or setting the Clock Alarm? Also, is it possible?

Comment: +1. Pls tell if you found anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with the built-in alarm application, but would adding an event to the calendar work? Try using the [PIM APIs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Update_calendar_entry_info_565482_11.jsp) to do that.

[There was another question along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019823/blackberry-alarm-integeration/4726872), and I'm still curious: Why would someone want an outside application to reset the built-in alarm?